# Travis Could not authorize build request

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm getting this error for each and every project in my Github organization.

```
Could not authorize build request myorg/myproject
```

I searched everywhere but couldn't find any solutions or what causes this. 
How to troubleshoot this issue/integration?

Comment: Sounds like a problem outside of your responsibility. Would recommend shooting an email to support@travis-ci.com.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

'Could not authorize build request ...' usually occurs due to

1. A **plan is not selected**. Travis will not select the free plan automatically. Select the free or paid plan for your organization manually.
2. Selected **plan become inactive**. Go to settings and select the plan again.
3. Expiration of your paid **subscription**.
4. Ran out of free trial **build credits** available for private repositories.

Travis CI is always-free only for public repositories. The free plan also provides 10,000 build credits try out building private repositories. Read updated info on [Billing FAQ](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/billing-faq).

Comment: It also just happens randomly due to travis being the most unreliable CI service in existence.

Comment: Updated the answer with the experiences of [danmurphy1217](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65024569/4220846), [iriberri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41078031/4220846) and [Xonshiz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65705225/4220846).

Comment: although Travis.IC assign free plan for every new sign up, you still need to choose the free plan (active plan) in setting (tab) which is default free plan is disable I think.

Comment: This one worked! Though free plan was selected for my user account, it was NOT selected by default for the organization account which hosted github repo.  After I selected plan for the organization a/c, the build suceeded.

Comment: Lol. My "free" plan wasn't selected. Had to go in manually and "activate" it

Comment: Unbelievable, this actually worked. it seems like it automatically resets itself after a while because I had been using it for some time and stopped. When I recently came back to use it I started getting this error, so I had to go and select the free plan manually again in settings.

Answer (score 44):

It's also worth mentioning that this happens if you do not have a plan selected for your organization. First, you need to select a plan (Travis does not automatically select the free plan for you). Then, you can trigger a build and see if things work.

If that does not work, you're likely out of builds and will need to upgrade the account.

Comment: This was it for me. In Travis, I had the free plan selected for my user account, but no plan selected for the organization holding the repo. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: Wow, that was it for me too. I don't mean to be picky for a free service, but how difficult is it to display a useful error message like "no plan selected, please go to your settings and select a plan" ?

Answer (score 24):

Make sure your subscription even to the Free plan is OK. In my case it was ON for the Github user. However, it was not for the organization

Comment: Unbelievable how complicated they made this. Thanks for sharing your solution, it works.

Comment: Both Org and User was the key here, Strange that such a simple validation does not have a better and clearer error message.

Comment: Yes it's the most complex weird menu system that bowls one over to figure out what is the active state.

Answer (score 11):

I am using a free version of travis. I got this error because I didn't signup for a plan (so stupid :( ) but later I did. I signed up for a free plan and the build started.

Answer (score 8):

I found [this issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/issues/733) in the Travis CI docs repo in which another user is describing the same problem.

According to a response from the Travis team: "'Could not authorize build request for ... ', usually means that the account ran out of trial builds or has not an active subscription on travis-ci.com".

Comment: purchased paid monthly subscription and still getting this ....

Comment: Yep - travis is a joke - i am insulted that they continue to charge me for a service that seems to be unavailable most of the time. What is the point of a CI service that requires constant manual intervention. This last event is the last straw for our team. We have done in house CI for almost 20 years but the latest client insisted on Travis. I have just told them that if they insist on forcing us to use this garbage they can find another contractor.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old thread, but had to share an update in 2020.
This issue could be because of multiple reasons.

1. Like others mentioned, your subscription ended or you don't have a
   plan selected for your org.
2. This was my case: I am on free plan and I had a private repository.
   Travis CI seems to be throwing error for this as well. As soon as I
   made that repository Public, the builds started.

Comment: they should explicitly tell you that this is due to your subscription

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the problem when I try to build a fork.

Context : I'm member of an organisation with a valid subscription.

To work silently tu tune the build config (and build tasks config) without alert other devs, I've fork the **private** repo on my own account.

There I can't use travis. :(

There is probably good reason, but I won't change my model so I would search an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I want to pull my hair out. For me, I had a plan enabled for my org and user. For reasons I can't explain, I had initially enabled it for the group level (and was using travis successfully), but then weeks later it then forgot my plan choice...

I had to go to my org settings > repos > choose group > plan > select free plan.

Oy vey.